# Jenkins and JIra docker image connection

Tags: jenkins, jira, docker-network

I want to integrate my Jira, Jenkins, and confluence. I have configured all the software with the help of a docker image. i.e., Jenkins -- Port 8082, Jira -- Port 8081, confluence -- Port 8090. 
For Jira – Jenkins Integration, I used "Jira Issue Updater," but Jenkins console is troughing an error – 
Unable to connect to REST service 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)Finished: SUCCESS

My fundamental question — Is it possible to connect two docker images because, by default, Jenkins and Jira's opening port are 8080. Still, I configured it as per my convenience (All docker images are in one docker network, and I could able to ping Jira's IP from Jenkins instance means Jira is reachable to Jenkins).
I am a bit confused about this integration. I need some support from community members.

Comment: If you have correctly exposed the port during the container creation then it shouldn't be any problem. It's not clear how you run all these three containers. Please list the full commands that you've used to run Jenkins, Confluence, and Jira, and I can help verify if they should communicate with each other.

Comment: I am using a shell script for Jira and Confluence.                                                      
Jenkins docker image:- docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8082:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts

Comment: Jira Shell Script                                                                                                            #!/bin/bash

export OPT=/opt/atlassian/jira
export APP=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira

#docker volume rm vol-jira-opt
#docker volume rm vol-jira-app
#docker volume create vol-jira-opt
#docker volume create vol-jira-app

docker rm -f jira
docker run -d --name="jira" --mount source=vol-jira-opt,target=$OPT --mount source=vol-jira-app,target=$APP -p 8081:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest                       same script for wiki as well.....

Comment: @aharith, thanks for your suggestions and prompt response!  The issue is resolved. I used docker container IP instead of localhost, and now I can communicate with two containers.